# Visual Studio Permanently Disable Overwrite

Tags: visual-studio, insert, overwrite

I have a minor annoyance with Visual Studio. In the bottom right hand corner of Visual Studio, there is a INS/OVR button to toggle Insert/Overwrite. I **always** have this button set to INS, and I always want it to be set to INS.

However, sometimes when I build the solution, Visual Studio changes this back to OVR. I have to click on the button to change it back to INS, which is slightly inconvenient.

I do not know why this setting sometimes changes.
Is there anyway I can permanently disable the overwrite mode in Visual Studio or prevent solution builds from changing this setting?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think you can permanently turn insert/overwrite off. Are you accidentally pressing insert on your keyboard? You can press the insert key on your keyboard or Shift+0 on the numpad to toggle it back again.

Comment: It appears that I was just accidentally pressing the Insert key on the keyboard when trying to backspace.

Comment: make sure your numlock is on :)

Comment: @elaine-lin I don't think you are, at least not always—it happens to me too from time to time, and I have the insert key disabled in my Logitech preferences. And it's annoying as hell to switch off overwrite this way because I always have to go into the Logitech preferences and switch the insert key *on* just to disable it. Ugh. I did now set a special, complicated (not easy to accidentally press) shortcut as per Chase Florell's answer below to disable it, but this has to be a bug in VS, it happens nowhere else.

Comment: Shift+0 (zero) worked for me; I'm using a Mac keyboard and double-clicking "OVR" did nothing. See Chase Florell's answer below to remove the shortcut bindings that allow you to accidentally turn on overwrite mode.

Answer (score 75):

Visual Studio, Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, remove the shortcut binding for `Edit.OvertypeMode`

Comment: The answer to the question and highly recommended !

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Works when keyboards do not have in INS key  (e.g. apple keyboards) 

Works in latest VS2019 layout which does not have a INS/ORV button.

Allows for a permanent Fix.

Comment: Thanks. But VS UI in Chinese doesn't allow search in English names. I'm still struggling to find its UI name in Chinese. OK got - it's "编辑.改写模式"

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes visual studio wont disable overtype even if you hit insert with numlock on, If this happens just close script and open it again and it will work. This is a bug in visual studio.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Visual Studio Code's settings and type "overtype" in the search bar, and set it to 'never'.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: Its not visual studio code, its visual studio

Comment: This answer is not correct for current builds of Visual Studio Code. Works for Visual Studio Community Edition. Please clarify.