# Is there a way to disable the overtype cursor in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: cursor, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. I'd like to be able to click and always have the skinny cursor come up, as opposed to the overtype cursor (the cursor that, when you type a character, replaces the character underneath it). Is there an extension for VS2019 that can provide this functionality?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the "insert" key on your keyboard ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Permanently Disable Overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164650/visual-studio-permanently-disable-overwrite)

Comment: Yup, hitting the insert key toggles overtype on/off. Thank you Laurent!

Answer (score 0):

Use the insert button on your keyboard to turn it on and off.

[image]